# target of assignment expands to non-language object

Tags: r

I want to make some calculations using loop in R.

I try `assign` but it still does not work well.

Can anyone give me a hint about how to setting up correct variable in R, please?

```
# My data
data <- read.table(textConnection("
              a1       a2       
a1    1.00000000  0.4803088
a1    0.48030878  1.0000000 

"), header = TRUE)

no <- 2

for (k in 1:no){

  paste0("dat.",k)  <- aggregate(data[,c(paste0("a",k),paste0("b",k), paste0("b",k))],list(data$id),mean)
  paste0("cor.",k) <- cor(paste0("dat.mean.",k),use = "complete.obs")   

  paste0("cal.",k) <- as.data.frame(paste0("dat.mean.",k)) 
  paste0("lm.",k) <- lm(paste0("a",k) ~ paste0("b",k),data = paste0("lm.cal.",k))

}
```

Comment: `paste0()` returns a character value. You cannot assign values to characters (ie `"apple"<-3` doesn't make sense in R). Do you need these variables to persist after the loop?

Comment: Thanks, would you mind giving me an quick example? Then I can follow your hint to finish it.

Comment: @MrFlick Uhm. `"apple"<-3` makes perfect sense in R, and executes successfully. I fully agree that it makes no sense whatsoever *outside* R but R is stupid and disagrees.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Good point. Silly variable quoting. is there a better way to explain why that doesn't work.

Comment: @MrFlick Unfortunately no, precisely due to variable quoting. The assignment rules in R are thus infuriatingly inconsistent — at least until you get to the point where you understand what `f(something, ...) <- value` expands to, which requires an advanced understanding of R. The easiest way may be to say that the left-hand side of an assignment must either be a variable, or have a variable as its left-most sub-expression part (after the function name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which language you are coming from (SAS maybe?) but R is a proper functional programming language and doesn't use things like macros to automate tasks. Here's a more R-like way to approach the problem

```
no <- 2
results <- lapply(1:no, function(k) {

  # use aggregate function to make correlation calculation. 

  this_dat_mean  <- aggregate(data[,c(paste0("y", c("f","p","c"), "_",k))], list(data$id), mean)
  this_cor <- cor(this_dat_mean, use = "complete.obs") 
  #write.table(this_cor, "file_path", row.names=T, col.names=T, quote=F)

  # calculate the lm

  this_lm_cal <- as.data.frame(this_dat_mean)
  this_lm <- lm(reformulate(paste0("yc_",k), paste0("yf_",k)), data = this_lm_cal)
  #write.table(this_lm, "file_path2", row.names=T, col.names=T, quote=F)

  list(lm=this_lm, cor=this_cor)
})
```

Notice that we use a function to iterate over the inputs of interest. This function has a bunch of local variables. We can return a list of values that we want to preserve from the function. We can get at them by looking at

```
 results[[1]]$lm 
 results[[2]]$cor
```

for example. It's better to create a (possibly named) list of values in R than to create a bunch of similarly named variables.

The `lm` model isn't a data.frame so you can't use `write.table` with that. Not sure what the goal was there.

Comment: I don't use rstudio so I'm not sure what you are talking about. What specifically do you want to see that you can't see now?

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, I second the point by MrFlick and suggest rewriting your code.

However, as I sometimes myself prefer dynamically generated variables in some situations and R is messy and do allow you to do so in selective ways (some things work, some do not), I would like to briefly explain you how:

```
> k=4
> paste0("lm.", k)
[1] "lm.4"

> paste0("lm.", k) <- 1515
Error in paste0("lm.", k) <- 1515 : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object

> assign ( paste0("lm.", k) , 1515 )

> paste0("lm.", k)
[1] "lm.4"

> eval(parse(text = paste0("lm.", k) ))
[1] 1515

> str(eval(parse(text = paste0("lm.", k) )))
 num 1515

> str(paste0("lm.", k) )
 chr "lm.4"
```

in summary: every time you use a glued-together variable, you have to refer to it through eval/parse. And remember that `<-`will not work as opperator - use `assign()`