# Rstudio plot viewer limited to number of observations or is it an issue with my R codes?

Tags: r, plot, graph, ggplot2

I am using `RStudio` and I am having an issue with a `ggplot2` graph. My data set has around 86,200 observations; so I am expecting these points to show up in my plot but strangely it is showing only one point in the middle of the plot.

```
ggplot(mydata,aes("Package Revenue EXCL VAT","Total Spending",colour=PropertyCode, size=5, alpha=0.5)) + geom_point()
```

The 2 columns used for the scatterplot are numeric columns. Running a `str(mydata)` gives the following for those 2 columns:

```
Package Revenue EXCL VAT: num

Total Spending: num
```

And this how the plot shows in the plot viewer window of RStudio (I have excluded the legends from the screen capture):

[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you probably need to get rid of the quotation marks in aes()

Comment: that's the problem, you are plotting two character vectors against each other instead of the variables you want. Getting rid of the quotation marks fixes this, but you probably want to rename your variables to something without spaces

Comment: or use backticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments said, use identifiers, not character strings. As you can see in your plot, you have one point, and its coordinates are, literally, the discrete values x = “Package Revenue EXCL VAT” and y = “Total Spending”.

In addition, you need to remove the fixed properties from the aesthetics and put them into the geometry instead: otherwise ggplot2 will map them to constant but arbitrary values (i.e. not the ones you want).

```
ggplot(mydata) +
    aes(`Package Revenue EXCL VAT`, `Total Spending`, color = PropertyCode) +
    geom_point(size = 5, alpha = 0.5)
```

(With added formatting cleanup.)

In case that’s unclear, the backticks in the above code don’t delimit character strings, they delimit *identifiers*: in R, `` `foo` `` is identical to `foo`. However, backticks allows you to use otherwise invalid characters in the identifier. This includes spaces.

The matter is confused by the fact that [R allows you to use quoted strings instead of backtick identifiers in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43350988/target-of-assignment-expands-to-non-language-object#comment73766436_43350988). But `aes` *isn’t* one of these cases, and if you want to keep your sanity you shouldn’t use this confusing feature of R.

Comment: I get an error message when running the codes you proposed:
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  object 'Package Revenue EXCL VAT' not found
Does that have to do with the spaces in the column headings?

Comment: the `aes()` should be included in the first `ggplot` function `ggplot(mydata,aes(....))`

Comment: @Niek No, there’s absolutely no need for that.

Comment: @user3115933 It seems that you misspelled the column name (I just copied and modified your code). Check carefully that your column name is spelled *exactly* the same. Maybe there are leading or trailing spaces? Check what `colnames(mydata)` displays.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks Konrad! My fault...I indeed wrongly spelled the column name.